# The argument type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. The error is showed in the screenshot below

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[Hello, I've been trying to make a Quiz application in Flutter and came upon this error. I am trying to connect my app to the Firebase Firestore database but can't go further that this. Thank you for the help :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA5Bk.png)

Comment: Please click on the link above for the error screenshot

Comment: instead of Map  quizData  give  Map<String,dynamic> quizData.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

The collection **Quiz** is expecting a type **Map<String, dynamic>** and you are setting the quizData as **Map<dynamic, dynamic>**.

For the problem to be solved you need to define the quizData in the expected format. Look at the code change below:

```
Future<void> addQuizData(Map<String, dynamic> quizData, String quizId)
```